# Ports with C++ Server/Client applications

Tags: client-server, firewall, tunnel, transport

If I create a c++ server/client application, the port I used to communicate does it need to be open on the router of the server and client machine

Or what other approach could I take?  the client computer needs to receive information from the server but I am not able to have any ports opened because it is on a school network....

[edit]

Hmm My setup is a php page running on a server say when I press hello, the server makes a ssh connection through php and sends shell commands to the machine.  The server is running off of a school server which I do have ssh access to and run all my things from there.  The client computer will be my pc running off of the school wifi which is not connected to the server.  The server will try to make a ssh connection to the public ip of my computer running off of the school wifi(no ports open/can ssh out but no ssh in).  Will these methods you mention make this possible, in particular the connect.c since I can't run putty off of the server, and the connect.c I could call from the php.

Comment: retagged question; consider moving to superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should provide additional information. Is your appication transport protocol TCP or UDP? *"it is on a school network"*: which computer is on a network were you cannot open any ports? The client? The server? Both? Do you expect connections from the Internet, or just within the school network?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of language is highly irrelevant here.

There don't need to be ports 'open' on any router, unless your traffic must pass through it. On normal peer hosts in the same network (or subnet) there would hardly be any firewall policy, not even in schools.

Technically it is possible for the switch to block peer-2-peer traffic (meaning traffic not destined to the outgoing gateway), but that is not very usual.

Of course, if the school doesn't allow outbound (WAN) traffic on most ports, tough luck, and they're absolutely right :)

You can look at

- ssh (with tunnels -L, -D and -R options, perhaps -o GatewayPorts on)
- [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org)
- [connect.c](http://bent.latency.net/bent/git/goto-san-connect-1.85/src/connect.html)
- [http-tunnel](http://www.http-tunnel.com/html/)

All very readily googled

Comment: Oh, don't forget the obvious: use ports that are open. By the way, if you're behind a proxy or NAT-ting firewall, you'll have to rely on outbound connection only unless you can configure port forwarding on the router

Comment: I've added more to the question, look up.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a TCP/IP connection, only the *server* port needs to be accessible by the client. The connection is full-duplex, therefore data can flow from the client to the server and vice-versa.

If you are using UDP for your application, which is a connection-less protocol, what happens depends heavily on the firewall or router and whether it performs connection tracking for your service or not.

Unless you provide some additional information on your service and the network setup on both the client and the server side, we cannot provide more concrete information.

Comment: The server is a dedicated school server students use for html, php, things like that.  The server I have access to through ssh.  The client will be on the school wifi which I don't have ssh access to.  The server will be the one doing most of the work.  So the server would need to have ssh access to the client.  My idea was possibly making a script on the client that constantly ssh's into the server and checks to see if any commands were passed, if the server received say the hello button press that would be a command, the query would return whatever command to the client and run it.